# Publishing from BOT Composer Fails when creating from Existing resources when the APP is Single Tenant

Tags: botframework

500 Internal Server Error in Web Chat after publishing from Bot Composer From Existing Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Please make the BOT Solution hosting model asInprocess instead of OutOfProcess in Web.Config

2. Add 2 extra keys in AppSettings.json for Single Tenant App .Since BOT composer considers default as MultiTenant .MicrosoftAppType and MicrosoftAppTenantId keys should be added manually to appsettings.
"MicrosoftAppId": "XXXXXXXXX",
"MicrosoftAppType": "SingleTenant",
"MicrosoftAppTenantId": "XXXXXXXX",